# How to add multiple dictionaries to a set Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries:

```
x = {"Name": "A"}
y = {"Name": "B"}
z = {"Name": "C"}

all_dictionaries = {}
all_dictionaries.update(x)
all_dictionaries.update(y)
all_dictionaries.update(z)
print(all_dictionaries)
```

The output is

```
{'Name': 'C'}.
```

But I would like it to print the following (one big set containing all declared dictionaries):

```
{{"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"}}
```

The `update()` doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: {{"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"}} is not a dictionary, it's a set

Comment: `{{"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"}}` is not a dictionary. It is a `set` literal and will give you a TypeError, since `dict` is not hashable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you can join the three dictionaries into a set (or list).

```
all_dictionaries = [x, y, z]
```

This would look like:
`[{"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"}]`

or you can give each of the dictionaries a key.

```
all_dictionaries = {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z}
```

which would look like: `{"x": {"Name": "A"}, "y": {"Name": "B"}, "z": {"Name": "C"}}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nested dictionary:

```
nested_dict = dict(x={"Name": "A"}, y={"Name": "B"}, z={"Name": "C"})

print(nested_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'x': {'Name': 'A'}, 'y': {'Name': 'B'}, 'z': {'Name': 'C'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The notation that looks like a dictionary with no values represents a datatype called "set," which is not a dictionary.

Since set can't contain items that are unhashable (like dictionaries), you must choose another datatype to work with.

You can use a list or tuple to group many keys into one container.

```
[{"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"}]  # List
({"Name": "A"}, {"Name": "B"}, {"Name": "C"})  # Tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries use a combination of a key and a value to store data, so it wouldn't be possible to do something like that.

You could either use an array (which is actually a list in python) to store multiple dictionaries like this:

```
x = {"Name": "A"}
y = {"Name": "B"}
z = {"Name": "C"}
array = [x, y, z]
print(array)      # [{'Name': 'A'}, {'Name': 'B'}, {'Name': 'C'}]
```

Or you could keep them in a tuple like so:

```
x = {"Name": "A"}
y = {"Name": "B"}
z = {"Name": "C"}
tuple = (x, y, z)
print(tuple)      # ({'Name': 'A'}, {'Name': 'B'}, {'Name': 'C'})
```

You can freely iterate both with a for loop, you can access the array indexes manually like you'd normally do too:

```
# Using the array from the first example
array[0]  # {'Name': 'A'}
```

Keep in mind that tuples are unchangeable while arrays are more flexible in python.